# Which generics should I use

Tags: c#, generics

I need to store a list of `int`-`string` key-value pairs with a requirement to preserve the order in which items were added. Once it is initialized, it does not change, i.e. nothing added or removed..

At first I thought of using `Dictionary<int,string>` and everytime I need to access the items use

```
foreach(var entry in dict.OrderBy(e=>e.Key)) { } //as Key is `int`
```

However everytime ordering does not seem to be the best option to use.

Now I've come to an idea to have a `List<Tuple<int, string>>`, as soon as `List<T>` guarantees the order of items.

So, is there a better option?

Comment: @pst the data's going to be accessed through `foreach` + by the element's index in the collection

Comment: Do you ever need to look up the value by the key?

Comment: @Habib: The question explicitly states: "a requirement to preserve the order in which items were added" - which is *not* what SortedDictionary does.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes, Missed that, I actually got confused by `dict.OrderBy(e=>e.Key)` in the question

Comment: @pst Ordering the dictionary was only a workaround. I need to access items in the order they were added in the first place, not in the order resulting after `OrderBy`...

Comment: @JonSkeet each keyvalue pair needs to be accessed by the index it was originally added to the collection. The value is not going to be searched by the key.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Read up on IList/[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) then .. don't make the problem complicated: "[List] Represents a *strongly typed* list [or *sequence*] of objects that can be *accessed by index* .."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the proposed possibilities:

- `Dictionary` doesn't guarantee the order of the items
- `SortedDictionary` sorts the items, but *not* in the order you added them (it sorts based on key comparison),
- `OrderedDictionary` keeps the order, but it's not generic and would introduce unnecessary casting and boxing.

So I think you should use `List<Tuple<int, string>>`. It preserves order and it's good enough for iteration using `foreach` and indexed access. If you know the size in advance, you could use an array as well, or a read only collection type, as [Cuong Le suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641481/93652).

Comment: AFAIK, Dictionaries are hashed and stored for O(1) access

Comment: @Aniket Yes, they are optimized for this kind of access time, but the cost of this efficiency is that the order of items cannot be guaranteed to be preserved. After all, the key needs to be hashed before the decision is made in which bucket to put the pair.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow duplicate key, `List<Tuple<int, string>>` would be the best choice. In order make your list as read-only, you can public read-only list after initialization:

```
 var readonlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<Tuple<int, string>>(yourlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `Dictionary` seems suitable as a data structure, it does not guarantee order of items.

List does not seem proper as it does not fit well with the data structure you are trying to store.

You may use an `OrderedDictionary` [which guarantees the order of items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in orderedDictionary)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` is not generic actually. The question is about generics in the first place.